# C# sending files over internet

Tags: c#, file, tcp, send

I managed to send binary data through TCP using `NetworkStream` and Sockets.
My only problem is that when I send larger files like few hundred KB images, they don't get transferred correctly, the half of the image is missing. On the server side I `Socket.Send` to transfer data. On the client side I use `Socket.BeginReceive` with a `1024` sized buffer that's getting written into a `MemoryStream`, later I use `new Bitmap(Stream)` to convert that `MemoryStream` into an image that can be displayed in a `PictureBox`.

What method should I use to avoid data loss?

Edit: code posted

```
            listener = new TcpListener(myAddress, 86);
            listener.Start();
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            ns = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (fileTransfer)
            {
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                do
                {
                    int length = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                    // with this line added the data loss apparently disappears
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                } while (ns.DataAvailable);
                UpdateData();
                ms.Dispose();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            ns.Dispose();
            client.Close();
            listener.Stop();
```

Edit: the data is still corrupt sometime even with the sleep method.

Comment: Please post your code, so one may spot the error.

Comment: Post your code. Without that we'd just be guessing.

Comment: This seems ok, so assuming it's not a network issue you have a bug somewhere either on the sending or the receiving side, we'd need to see that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it by sending the size of the data before sending the actual data. The reason it didn't work that I wrongly assumed that the transfer was immediate. That's why the Sleep() method in the receiver loop made a difference but did NOT solve the problem. I understand that I can't rely on DataAvailable in this context. Even checking the length of the received data won't work because the client might send data after the loop has finished. Checking the file size (if the data is bigger than the buffer on the receiver side) is the best solution I found so long.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change this loop:

```
do
{
    int length = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, length);
    // with this line added the data loss apparently disappears
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
} while (ns.DataAvailable);
```

into:

```
do
{
    int length = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, length);
} while (length > 0);
```

That is, read until the end of data (i.e `ns.Read` returns no data). `Read` blocks until there are some data or the socket is closed (or some exception is thrown). I removed the useless sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (at a guess) you are not reading from the stream on the client side correctly.

You need to read the result of the EndReceive ( ) method to see how much data you actually read - it may not be the size of your buffer (1024 bytes in this case)

So:
a) When calling BeginReceive are you passing a callback?
b) If Yes, are you reading the result of this and writing the appropriate amount of bytes into your memory stream?

ie:

```
public void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult result)
{

    var buffer = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
    int bytesRead = socket.EndReceive();
    memoryStream.Write (buffer, 0, bytesRead);//bytesRead may not be 1024!
}
```

Comment: good point, but I'm aware of this, it's seems to be a problem with NetworkStream.DataAvailable reporting false even though there's still data waiting to be transferred.

Comment: @Tibor Hencz You have misunderstood the DataAvailable property. It doesn't tell you that the sending side might have some future data to send you, it tells you if there is data available, at your receiving endpoint right *NOW*. What if you read faster than the other side write, and at this particular time, not data have reached your host , but in 3 nanoseconds some data will arrive ? You should keep reading until the sending side closes the stream (or until a large timeout occurs)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what my code is supposed to do, check if there's data arrived on the device and reads it if there is. I saw it in this example code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx